Subscriber server name for a replication of SQL Server
When I am preparing to setup a new replication in an new server as an old server. I noticed that the subscriber displayed in the subscription properties is ADPASDB6006
but what I used T-SQL find is PASDMAIN 
So my questions are:
Q1. Why are the subscriber different? If the ServerName in the sys.names is wrong how to change it?
Q2. How to link table MSsubscriber_info to other tables to get more subscriber info, like table MSpublications?
here is my code
--get the publication, article subscriber and destination_db INFO USE distribution;
GO

SELECT 
    @@SERVERNAME as PublisherServer,
    pub.name as Distributor,
    p.publication,
    p.publisher_db,
    a.article_id,
    a.article,
    sub.name as SubscriberName,
    s.subscriber_id,
    s.subscriber_db,
    s.subscription_type,
    p.publication_id,
    a.source_object,
    a.destination_object
FROM 
    dbo.MSpublications p
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MSarticles a ON p.publication_id = a.publication_id
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MSsubscriptions s ON a.article_id = s.article_id
left join master.sys.servers sub on s.subscriber_id=sub.server_id
left join master.sys.servers pub on p.publisher_id=pub.server_id
where s.subscriber_db<>'virtual'

select * from MSsubscriber_info
select name, server_id from sys.servers where server_id=2

